# Title for a non-PhD researcher?

Tags: phd, research-undergraduate, independent-researcher, titles, non-academic-staff

I do not have a PhD, nor am I pursuing one, in the United Kingdom.

What title could I be given, if I worked as a paid researcher at a university, but I was not a PhD student or PhD graduate? The level of work would be at PhD level.

It might be misleading to call myself a researcher, as I thought that only applied to either students or people that passed their PhD dissertations.

Comment: Generally your title is something chosen by your employer, rather than what you call yourself.

Comment: @BryanKrause They are trying to think of a title to give me, sorry for not including this.

Comment: In my Uni, a person with such a job is called a "Research assistant."

Answer (score 5):

Actually, "Researcher" or "Independent Researcher" should be fine. There is no *official* definition and the terms are merely descriptive.

Another possibility is to use a title used by your employer for your role, if that seems suitable. Sometimes a title like "Research Associate" or such is used.

But there is no implication in the term *researcher* that you have any particular qualification. Your user name here is suitable, if that is, in fact, descriptive of what you do.

But note that it isn't actually a "title" in the sense of something conferred on you by authority like "Professor" is. It is just a description of one of your roles.

Comment: I think "Independent Researcher" is incorrect, because they are technically part of a university and being paid by the said university.

Comment: I'm confused by the last sentence here (US perspective). "Professor" is just a job title that tends to be associated with specific rights, duties, and academic tenure. But there are cases where the title is used rather flexibly even by well-known universities, e.g. to hire out-of-office politicians as speakers. I've seen variants increasingly used for postdocs as well ("Research Assistant Professor").

Comment: @AnonymousM, I don't understand. If a university decides you are a professor, then you are a professor. Qualifications may apply, I agree. And _Full Professor_ is a specific variant. I'm actually "Professor Emeritus", another variant. One real exception, I know of is (was) [Professor Irwin Corey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin_Corey)

Comment: @Buffy Right. If a University decides you are a Research Associate, you are also a Research Associate. These two job titles are the same in this way, they are a description of a role. Appending "Professor" before a name e.g. in professional or social correspondence is just a tradition of the particular job title.

Answer (score 3):

- Research fellow
- Visiting scholar

"Research fellow" would imply a more permanent position. If you will be under someone's supervision, you could also use:

- Research assistant

Comment: "Research assistant" carries a connotation that the person is not expected to have enough creative input to get co-authorship on papers.  (Although sometimes they do have substantial creative input, and sometimes when they do have substantial creative input they get denied co-authorship anyway.)  "Research fellow" is widely used for postdocs.

Comment: @DanielHatton Is that a general rule in the UK?

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- Not a rule, just a phenomenon I've observed to be commonplace.

Answer (score 2):

Further to @Allure's answer, I've seen "pre-doctoral research associate" and "research trainee".